# How to filter a query based on dynamic number of parameters

Tags: c#, sql, .net, ado.net, parameterized-query

How to handle a combination of parameters in a query based on user selections.

For Example:

```
public DataTable GetStudents(int fromYear,int toYear,int camp_code,int fac_code,int dep_code)
        {
            StringBuilder cmdTxt = new StringBuilder();
            cmdTxt.Append(" SELECT register_no,name ");
            cmdTxt.Append(" FROM student WHERE year BETWEEN ? AND ? ");
            cmdTxt.Append(" AND camp_code = ?  AND fac_code = ? AND dep_code =? ");//Is a variable

            using (var myIfxCmd = new IfxCommand(cmdTxt.ToString(), con))
            {
                myIfxCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                myIfxCmd.Parameters.Add("year1", IfxType.Integer);
                myIfxCmd.Parameters.Add("year2", IfxType.Integer);
                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    con.Open();
                }
                myIfxCmd.Parameters[0].Value = fromYear;
                myIfxCmd.Parameters[1].Value = toYear;
                //..............
            }
```

---

- Organization contains set of camps.
- Camp contains set of faculties.
- Faculty contains set of departments.

In this code I want to control `(int camp,int fac,int dep)`.
If the user selects all camps then `camp = 0`  => The whole organization, So I want to ignore

```
" AND camp_code = ?  AND fac_code = ? AND dep_code =? "
```

And in this case I have just two parameters for `fromYear,toYear`

---

If the user selects a specific `camp <> 0` and wants to select all faculties then `fac_code = 0` => all faculties, So I want to ignore:

```
" AND fac_code = ? AND dep_code =? "
```

And in this case I have just three parameters for `fromYear,toYear,camp_code`

---

If the user selects a specific `camp <> 0` and selects a specific faculty then wants to select all the departments under this fac then `dep_code = 0` => all departments, So I want to ignore:

```
" AND dep_code =? "
```

And in this case I have just four parameters for `fromYear,toYear,camp_code,fac_code`

---

If the user selects all three arguments <> 0 then we will include every thing having 5 parameters.

---

I want to make it dynamic and flexible to meet these criteria. I solve it but overwhelmed by dozens of `(IF-ELSE)` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something similar to what kowie le roux suggested, only I believe it's the *parameter* that is zero, not the value in the database.  As such, if you use yoda notation and an "in" clause, I think you can cause the where condition to be true if either the specified field matches or a zero-value was furnished:

```
select register_no, name
from student
where
  year between ? and ? and
  ? in (camp_code, 0) and
  ? in (fac_code, 0) and
  ? in (dep_code, 0)
```

You would need to declare and assign all five parameters.

Also, for what it's worth, I don't know what Ifx is -- Informix?  If so, see if it supports named parameters.  If it does, something like this helps make the code a lot more maintainable.

```
string sql = @"
    select register_no, name
    from student
    where
        year between @FROM and @THRU and
        @CAMP in (camp_code, 0) and
        @FAC in (fac_code, 0) and
        @DEP in (dep_code, 0)
";

using (var myIfxCmd = new IfxCommand(sql, con))
{
    myIfxCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    myIfxCmd.Parameters.Add("@FROM", IfxType.Integer);
    myIfxCmd.Parameters.Add("@THRU", IfxType.Integer);
    myIfxCmd.Parameters.Add("@CAMP", IfxType.Integer);
    myIfxCmd.Parameters.Add("@FAC", IfxType.Integer);
    myIfxCmd.Parameters.Add("@DEP", IfxType.Integer);
```

The assignments would look the same from there.

Answer (score 1):

As always, breaking this into smaller bits makes life easier. Don’t write methods that do too much, break it into smaller bits.

As a bonus, if you use extension methods you can even achieve fluent syntax but that isn’t really necessary:

```
static IfxCommand GetStudents() { //create unfiltered query here ... }
static IfxCommand FilterByYears(
    this IfxCommand command,
    DateTime start,
    DateTime end) { ... }
 static IfxCommand FilterByCampus(
     this IfxCommand command,
     int campusId) { ... }
  //etc.
```

Now in each `FilterBy...` method you modify the command accordingly (or not) and you pass it along. No spaghetti code, each method only takes care of one filter.

And you build your query easily:

```
var command =
   GetStudents().FilterByYears(start, end)
                .FiltersByCampus(campus)
                .FilerByFaculty(fac);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I ‘m a little confused about the query here, I will be grateful if you can clarify the idea with code more please ☺️

Answer (score 1):

You would want your SQL to look something like this:

```
    cmdTxt.Append(" SELECT register_no,name ");
    cmdTxt.Append(" FROM student WHERE year BETWEEN ? AND ? ");
    cmdTxt.Append(" AND (camp_code = ? OR camp_code = 0) AND (fac_code = ? or fac_code = 0) AND (dep_code = ? or dep_code = 0) ");
```

The above would mean that if camp_code is 0, dep_code is 0 and fac_code is 0, all would return. If camp_code <> 0, and dep_code and fac_code is 0, it will return the specific camp etc.